# How to infer node.js profiling results?

Tags: node.js, performance, profiling, performance-testing, v8

I have a simple nodejs application (app A) in Windows that listens to a port and as soon as it receives request it posts to another server (app B) and records the response in MongoDB.

App A (single thread, no cluster implemeneted yet) processes around 35 requests per second (measured using locust.io). The below is the profiling information of app A. 97.8%  of time is taken by the shared libraries out of which 93.5% is due to ntdll.dll. Is it normal or a potential bottleneck that can be fixed?

```
 [Summary]:
       ticks  total  nonlib   name
       6023    2.0%   87.8%  JavaScript
          0    0.0%    0.0%  C++
        502    0.2%    7.3%  GC
      300434   97.8%          Shared libraries
        834    0.3%          Unaccounted

 [Shared libraries]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
  287209   93.5%          C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
  12907    4.2%          C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
    144    0.0%          C:\windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
    133    0.0%          C:\windows\system32\KERNEL32.DLL
     25    0.0%          C:\windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
     15    0.0%          C:\windows\system32\mswsock.dll
      1    0.0%          C:\windows\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
[Bottom up (heavy) profile]:
  Note: percentage shows a share of a particular caller in the total
  amount of its parent calls.
  Callers occupying less than 2.0% are not shown.

[Bottom up (heavy) profile]:
  Note: percentage shows a share of a particular caller in the total
  amount of its parent calls.
  Callers occupying less than 2.0% are not shown.

   ticks parent  name
  287209   93.5%  C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
   6705    2.3%    C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
    831   12.4%      LazyCompile: <anonymous> C:\opt\acuity\proxy\nodejs\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:786:54
    826   99.4%        LazyCompile: *Callbacks.emit
```

Comment: did you find any solution? if yes, could you please share it .

Answer (score 0):

In a typical application (a mixture of CPU bound and I/O bound workloads) I would say the more the process was able to run among the CPU slots allotted to it, the better - that way we would see more CPU consumption in the user space, as opposed to the kernel space.

In Node.js, as the I/O is delayed until it is available to be actioned, and when they are ready to be actioned, we could see an increased activity in the OS space. If the massive usage of ntdll.dll is to carry out I/O, I would say this is not a concern, rather indication of a good performant system.

Do you have heavy profile showing the split-up in ntdll.dll? If they are pointing to win32 APIs / helper functions which facilitate I/O, then I would say this is a good sign of your system.